# Using ansible to shuffle list of dns servers

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this bit of templating code I inherited:

```
supersede domain-name-servers
      {% set comma = joiner(", ") -%}
      {%- for host in groups['consul_server_true'] -%}
        {%- if host in groups[dc_grp] -%}
          {{ comma() }}{{ hostvars[host]['private_ip_address']  }}
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%};
```

It does what it's supposed to, generates a `supersede domain-name-servers ip,ip,ip;` line.

What we'd like to do is stick a `| shuffle(seed=inventory_ansible_hostname)` in there so the order becomes predictably random.  My template foo isn't quite up to snuff, because what I managed to do is shuffle the digits of the ip addresses themselves :(.

Can anyone show me how I'd properly group things and feed them to shuffle so that the order of the elements is shuffled, not the elements themselves?

Comment: Doesn't `{%- for host in groups['consul_server_true'] | shuffle(seed=inventory_hostname) -%}` do the job ? Note that the var you want to use as seed does not contain "ansible" in its name as you wrote it in your question.

Comment: That absolutely does it!  I see where I made my mistake now, I was trying to get it in on the end as part of the join, where I should have just shuffled the input to the join!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you placed your filter in your template but if you shuffle the input list of server in the loop it should randomize as expected:

```
supersede domain-name-servers
      {% set comma = joiner(", ") -%}
      {%- for host in groups['consul_server_true'] | shuffle(seed=inventory_hostname) -%}
        {%- if host in groups[dc_grp] -%}
          {{ comma() }}{{ hostvars[host]['private_ip_address']  }}
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%};
```